# How to remove IMAP account from Thunderbird's "Grouped Inbox"

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have four IMAP accounts "merged" into one using Thunderbird 2's "Grouped inbox" view.

I want to take one of the four accounts out of the grouped view. It is a maintenance mailbox that contains a lot of status mails. Those mails tend to clog my "real" inbox.

I am able to edit the Inbox folder using "Properties". In the list that comes up, it is possible to de-select the maintenance mailbox and everything works fine. However, if I restart Thunderbird, it will forget what I de-selected and use all four mailboxes again.

Is there any way to make Thunderbird remember the change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version do you use? I use 3.1.2 and for me the deselected Inbox-folders (via *Select*) keep being deselected after a restart. So I'd suggest you to update your version.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: what if you set up a filter (either in Thunderbird or on the server) to have the status/maintenance E-Mails go into a subfolder of that IMAP account instead of the inbox?  That would bypass the issue.

(I don't know of any other way to do what you're asking in either TB2 or TB3.)